# Subnet creation exceeding number of hosts

Tags: ipv4, subnet, ip

I have a question, and I have some confusion.

I have to create subnets for six different teams. All IP addresses should start with 172.168.1.x only.

```
Team 1 -> 5 Hosts
Team 2 -> 16 Hosts
Team 3 -> 13 Hosts
Team 4 -> 37 Hosts
Team 5 -> 65 Hosts
Team 6 -> 12 Hosts
```

It looks like it is not possible. I think I have to reduce the host count from some team.

Can anyone can help?

Comment: Classful networking is dead. And even with the old definition of Classful an address starting with 178 can never ever be a Class C address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In other words you have a /24 network that you want to divide in 6 networks.

Let's reorder the teams by size:

```
Team 5 : 65 hosts  
Team 4 : 32 hosts  
Team 2 : 16 hosts  
Team 3 : 13 hosts  
Team 6 : 12 hosts  
Team 1 : 5 hosts
```

and compare them with subnet sizes:

A /24 network comprise 256 addresses from which you must remove the network, broadcast and gateway addresses leaving 253 addresses for hosts.

Similarly:

```
/25 : 125 hosts  
/26 :  61 hosts  
/27 :  29 hosts  
/28 :  13 hosts  
/29 :   5 hosts
```

So we see that we need at a minimum:

```
Team 5 : 65 hosts -> /25  
Team 4 : 32 hosts -> /26  
Team 2 : 16 hosts -> /27  
Team 3 : 13 hosts -> /28  
Team 6 : 12 hosts -> /28  
Team 1 :  5 hosts -> /29
```

### Can we divide a /24 network to fit all those networks in ?

A way to look at it would be:

- Divide the /24 in two /25 networks.
  The first /25 is assigned to `Team5`, the second /25 is further sub-netted.
- Divide the second /25 in two /26 networks.
  The first /26 is assigned to `Team4`, the second is further sub-netted.
- Divide the second /26 in two /27 networks.
  The first /27 is assigned to `Team2`, the second is further sub-netted.
- Divide the second /27 in two /28 networks.
  the two /28 are assigned to `Team3` and `Team6`.

Nothing left for `Team1`... ...too bad.

You could for example:

- Group Team 1 with another team (so both team will use the same
  network).
- User for another team 2 networks, i.e.:
  Separate the the first /25 that was assigned to Team 5 in two /26 networks.
  Assign the first one to the first 63 hosts of Team5.
  Subnet the second one in four /28 networks
  Assign the first /28 to the other members of Team 5, the second one to team 1 and you have two /28 available.

Comment: great.. clearly explained, one more quick question, what means writing the above in CIDR notation?